# How do you explicitly abandon a message in a azure function triggered from a topic message/subscription?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

Im using an azure function which is invoked every time a new message is published to a topic + SUBSCRIPTION ( NOT a queue!)

What exactly do I need to do within the azure function body to EXPLICITLY move it to the dead letter subqueue?

According to azure,

> Exceeding MaxDeliveryCount Queues and subscriptions each have a
>   QueueDescription.MaxDeliveryCount and
>   SubscriptionDescription.MaxDeliveryCount property respectively; the
>   default value is 10. Whenever a message has been delivered under a
>   lock (ReceiveMode.PeekLock), but has been either explicitly abandoned
>   or the lock has expired, the message BrokeredMessage.DeliveryCount is
>   incremented. When DeliveryCount exceeds MaxDeliveryCount, the message
>   is moved to the DLQ, specifying the MaxDeliveryCountExceeded reason
>   code.

From a c# code perspective , What exactly do they mean by

> "explicitly abandoned or the lock has expired"

Im only talking about topic/subscription here. Please no comments on service bus queues, just topic/subcription. (even if the logic is the same, I'm only interested in treating topic/subscription here. talking about services bus queues is just going to confuse the focus of the question)

Comment: As @SeanFeldman said you can't, one of your option would be to: Configure the `MaxDeliveryCount` to 1 and throw an exception when you want to dead letter message, it has draw backs but it can do the trick...

Answer (score 2):

You cannot explicitly dead-letter a message from an Azure Function. The function will dead-letter messages after going through all the retries.
Explicit dead-lettering is possible when using a C# client and implementing custom receiving logic.

BTW, subscription or queue, it doesn't matter. They both are queues.

Comment: What exactly is the retry logic? How can I configure retry logic when using azure functions which are triggered at the subscription level?

Comment: Retries applied by Functions runtime. Poison message handling can't be controlled or configured in Azure Functions. Service Bus handles poison messages itself. [source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus#trigger---configuration)

Comment: What would be the purpose of allowing a function to be executed based on a trigger of a service bus topic / sub if it doesn’t have the power to place a message into a place to be retried at a later point? I mean, how are people handling failed function invocations then? Especially if timing is important.

Comment: With Functions you're opting into how they work. It's a framework with its rules. There are number of configured retries a Function will attempt a message for processing and then move it to a poison/dead-letter queue. Once a message is dead-lettered, you'll need to build a mechanism to handle those.

Comment: What number of retries then does a function have by default?

Comment: [Five times](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue#trigger---hostjson-properties) for Storage Queues. For Azure Service Bus it will be  MaxDeliveryCount of the entity.

Comment: I’ve just been able to send a message to dead letter queue by throwing an exception within the function body. FYI. Only with queue though.

Comment: That's expected behaviour. When you throw in the function, message will be retired as the MaxDeliveryCount prescribed, and then it will be dead-lettered with the reason that it exceeded the maximum delivery count.

Comment: If its expected behavior then we can explicitly dead-letter a message from an azure function: by throwing an exception. Dont you think this goes against your answer slightly?

Comment: It doesn't. This is the default behavior for Azure Service Bus. Functions SDK just leverages that fact. Unlike Storage Queues. Cheers!

Comment: If you dont think it goes against your answer, how do you reconcile the fact that a message can be deadlettered explicitly in code by throwing an exception against your claim that it cannot happen?

Comment: It's not dead-lettered explicitly as you'd do with your own receiver. It's almost a ""side effect" of the ASB behavior when dead-lettering occurs naturally. Check your entity settings and Function log.

Comment: The azure function is the receiver.